# How can I calculate the 3 genres most frequent it in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe with one column and I need to return 3 most frequent genres.

> **INPUT**

```
    genres
0   Drama
1   Animation|Children's|Musical
2   Musical|Romance
3   Drama
4   Animation|Children's|Comedy
5   Action|Adventure|Comedy|Romance
6   Action|Adventure|Drama
7   Comedy|Drama
8   Animation|Children's|Musical
9   Adventure|Children's|Drama|Musical
10  Animation|Children's|Musical
11  Musical
12  Drama
13  Comedy
```

Drama 6
Musical 6
Children's 5
Animation 4
Comedy 4
Adventure 3
Action 2

> **OUTPUT** - A dataframe with:

```
  genres
0 Drama
1 Musical
2 Children's
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: You say you have dataframe with one column, but that doesn't look like one column?

Comment: I tried to separate in dummy table and after count the frequencies of columns, but not always will be the same columns can be others genres

Comment: Some [MCVE] of attempts would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `split` first , the do `stack` , then using `value_counts`

```
df.genres.str.split('|',expand=True).stack().value_counts().head(3)
Drama         6
Musical       6
Children's    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I need to pickup the name of genres, how can I put index name in list?

Comment: @Mariana `df.genres.str.split('|',expand=True).stack().value_counts().head(3).index.tolist()`